# Firebase cloud functions check db for non-existant data

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking for how to check if a documents exists in my cloud functions
My functions belows works fine when just incrementing an existing value, but now I'm trying to add functionality where it checks to see if the previous value exists and if it doesn't set as 1.

I've tried a different methods but I get things like "snapshot.exists" or "TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined at docRef.get.then.snapshot

```
var getDoc = docRef.get()
        .then(snapshot => {

            if (typeof snapshot._fieldsProto.count !== undefined) {
                console.log("haha3", snapshot._fieldsProto.count)

                var count = Number(jsonParser(snapshot._fieldsProto.count, "integerValue"));

                docRef.set({
                        count: count + 1
                    });
            }
            else {
                docRef.set({
                        count: 1
                    });
            }

        });
```

below is the code for the exists() error

```
var getDoc = docRef.get()
        .then(snapshot => {

            if snapshot.exists() {
                console.log("haha3", snapshot._fieldsProto.count)

                var count = Number(jsonParser(snapshot._fieldsProto.count, "integerValue"));

                docRef.set({
                        count: count + 1
                    });
            }
            else {
                docRef.set({
                        count: 1
                    });
            }

        });
```

The error for this code is:

> TypeError: snapshot.exists is not a function at docRef.get.then.snapshot

Comment: To check whether a document exists at a snapshot call [`DocumentSnapshot.exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#~exists). If that doesn't work for you, show the exact error message and the [minimal complete code that reproduces the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just added the code for the exists error

Comment: What is the error you get with that code?

Comment: TypeError: snapshot.exists is not a function at docRef.get.then.snapshot

Comment: What does `docRef` point to? If it's a query or collection, you're getting a `QuerySnapshot`, so you'll want to check `!QuerySnapshot.empty`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `docRef` either points to a collection or is a query. In that case your `snapshot` is of type `QuerySnapshot`.

To check if a query has any result, use [`QuerySnapshot.empty`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#empty).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I still got empty isnt a function (before it was exists isnt) but I was able to get it working with an undefined check.  I posted that code as another answer, feel free to tell me if anything about it stands out to you

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting errors saying either empty or exists were not functions (tried many iterations) so eventually I landed on just using an undefined check and it works perfectly.

```
var db = event.data.ref.firestore;

    var docRef = db.collection(userID).doc("joined").collection("total").doc("count");


    var getDoc = docRef.get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            console.log("augu1", snapshot)
            if (snapshot._fieldsProto === undefined) {
                console.log("digimon1")
                docRef.set({
                        count: 1
                    });
            }
            else {      
                console.log("haha31", snapshot._fieldsProto.count)

                var count = Number(jsonParser(snapshot._fieldsProto.count, "integerValue"));

                docRef.set({
                        count: count + 1
                    });
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem is much simpler than I imagined: `DocumentSnapshot.exists` is a read-only property, not a function. So the proper way to use it is:

```
if snapshot.exists()
```

Comment: Note here is that this differs between the Web and Node SDK.